# PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR not working - Windows 11

Tags: php, windows-11

I have "PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR" in my SYSTEM ENV VAR

```
L:\>echo %PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR%
C:\php\config
```

I run this:

```
php --ini
```

I get this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: C:\php\config
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Not what I expected. I expected a few INI file names to be listed.

PS: This is on a new PC build.
This worked just fine for previous Windows (10 and 11) machines.

EDIT:
Sample list of files:

- errors_logging.ini
- extensions.ini
- php.xdebug.ini

Comment: I apologize, but just to ask the obvious, that folder has files that end with `.ini`? I ask because Windows likes to hide file extensions sometimes

Comment: oh, always ask the OBVIOUS!
And yes, they all end in ".INI"

Comment: Okay, and just to be double clear, is it `.ini` or `.INI`. I don't know if the scanner is case-sensitive or not (I'm WSL on Windows), but the docs say `.ini`

Comment: as my edit showed, INI all lowercase.